# How to querySelect Vuejs element on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to querySelect the exact element that is click on vueJs

```
<a @click="myFunc()"> Click Me </a>
```

And edit this element using js querySelector

```
methods : {
 myFunc(){
  document.querySelector(this)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case, there is an easier solution than query select.

Html:

```html
<a @click="myFunc"> Click Me </a>
```

(note that I've removed the `()`)

Vue:

```
methods : {
 myFunc(e){
   console.log(e.target)
 }
}
```

You can use the event generated by the DOM instead of trying to search for the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use `ref`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {

    }
  },
  methods : {
     myFunc(){
      this.$refs.link.innerText = 'selected'
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <a ref="link" @click="myFunc"> Click Me </a>
</div>
```